# How Do I Make My Background Image Change Every 15 Seconds Or So Via CSS & JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

What I need it to do is change the background randomly every 15 seconds or so.
JS:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var curImgId = 0;
        var numberOfImages = 5; // Change this to the number of background images
        window.setInterval(function () {
            $('body').css('background-image', 
             'url(/images/background_images' + curImgId + '.jpg)');
            curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
        }, 15 * 1000);
    })();
</script>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    /*background-image:url(images/background_images/image1.jpg);
    background-image:url(images/background_images/image2.jpg);
    background-image:url(images/background_images/image3.jpg);
    background-image:url(images/background_images/image4.jpg);*/
    background:url(upload.js);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

A list of images I am going to use

```
http://mrsnapatya.net/screenshot1.png
```

the file directory is `/images/background_images/`

So any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

url function needs a string -

```
$('body').css('background-image','url("images/background_images/image' + curImgId + '.jpg")');
```

Comment: ok... there was another slash missing after background_images... too many bugs to fix dude. Edited the answer

Comment: it also didn't have the string `image` after background_images... again edited. i don't know what you tried. you can't have people fix your bugs here

Comment: Oh hey one last thing, when you load the page the image is a blank page, then it starts scrolling through images.